# Übersetzung von "Goodness knows we need it"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie übersetzt man die Phrase

> Goodness knows we need it.

ins Deutsche?

Ein [Beispiel](http://www.science.unsw.edu.au/opinion/opinion-science-communication-importance-evidence) von der Verwendung dieser Phrase:

> We are reaching out to tomorrow's scientists: with three decades of decline in interest in science in our high schools, **goodness knows we need it**.

Diese [Übersetzung](http://www.dict.cc/?s=goodness+knows) von "goodness knows" als "Wer weiß (denn)?" trifft nicht zu.

Comment: "Goodness" ist hier ein Euphemismus für "God".

Comment: @CarstenSchultz In welchem Sinne kann man _euphemistisch_ über Gott sprechen?

Comment: Indem man zum Beispiel "goodness" sagt, wenn man "God" meint aber nicht leichtfertig sagen möchte. Das ist wie "what the heck" statt "what the hell".

Comment: ‘Goodness knows’ is also a way for those of us who have no use for religion to avoid ‘God knows’ and ‘heaven knows’. When it’s used for that reason, it’s a substitute but not really a euphemism, and *weiß Gott* isn’t really an accurate translation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Nach drei Jahrzehnten mit schwindendem Interesse an den Naturwissenschaften in unseren Gymnasien haben wir das *weiß Gott* nötig.

Comment: Ich hätte das Wort "das" weggelassen: "...haben wir weiß Gott nötig". Bin ich da alleine?

Comment: @0x6d64 Vielleicht nicht allein, aber sicher auf dem Holzweg. Du kannst "das" ersetzen, durch "es" oder ein "richtiges" Objekt, aber nicht einfach weglassen. Und im gegebenen Kontext, in dem es ja noch einen Vorspann gibt, den Kilian nicht mit übersetzt hat, ist das Demonstrativpronomen "das" genau richtig: es verweist auf "reaching out to tomorrow's scientists" ("[wir] wenden uns an die Naturwissenschaftler von morgen"), also auf das, was nötig ist.

Answer (score 5):

Meist wird diese Phrase umgangssprachlich-spirituell übersetzt:

*Weiß der Himmel...*, hier z.B.: *...weiß der Himmel, wir können es brauchen.*
(aber eher nicht ...*wir brauchen es.*)

Comment: Kann man auch " weiß der Geier" in diesem Zusammenhang verwenden, ja?

Comment: Nein, "weiß der Geier" bedeutet das Gegenteil: "Ich weiß es nicht, und vermutlich weiß es niemand."

Comment: in the US, it is also common to say, "heaven knows we need it..."

Comment: "Weiss der Himmel" means the opposite of "weiss Gott" in that context. "Weiss der Himmel" is quite similar to "Weiss der Geier". "Weiss der Himmel" = only heaven/god knows, "Weiss der Geier" = nobody knows. "xyz haben wir weiss Gott noetig" = we need it and everybody knows it.